# CodeIgniter Paging class, active link not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the paging class of the codeigniter for the first time. Everything else is working fine, but whichever page I am going, the active link is always the [1] and it doesn't change. Also the next button is always linked to the first page. Culdn't figure out why ! Please help !

Controller

```
public function unverified_images()
{           
    $data['title'] = 'Choose from the below Images to verify them >>';
    $data['total_rows'] = $this->admin_model->all_unverified_images();

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/admin/admin/unverified_images';
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['total_rows']->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $config['num_links'] = 8;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['query'] = $this->db->where('image_status', 0)
                    ->get('tbl_img', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));
    $data['links']=$this->pagination->create_links();       
    $this->load->view('admin/image_verify', $data);
}

public function verify_image()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Choose from the below Images to verify them >>';
    $data['msg'] = $this->admin_model->verify_image();
    $data['query'] = $this->admin_model->all_unverified_images();
    redirect('admin/admin/unverified_images');
}
```

Model

```
function all_unverified_images()
{
    $this->db->where('image_status', 0);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_img');
    return $query;
}
```

View

```
   <?php echo $links; ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Sound like that CI can't figure out what page you supposed to be on.
Try adding the `uri_segment` or the `cur_page` for the `$config` array.

The `uri_segment` should tell CI what part of the url holds the current page number, from your example code it seem to be `4` (from the query) while CI's default is 3.